# Fire observer before method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, observer-pattern, observers

I have created the `observer` with the method:

`public function updated(User $user) {
    $user->status == 'disabled' ? abort(422, 'Aborted.') : '';
}`

I can update my user by the `post endpoint` on the method:

`public function updateStatus(User $user, $status) {
    $user->status = $status; // for our example it's disabled
    // updating user code
}`

The problem is: the code in observer is fired after the code in method what makes it unuseful because it does not work as I would wish. I'm guessing I do not understand observers correctly and I should put the logic into the method. Or am I wrong?

When does the actually observer fire? I registered it into the `AppServiceProvider (boot method)`.

Comment: because you use `updated` ? what about `updating`

Comment: or simple put the logic in your model ?

Comment: the event isn't fired until the model is 'saved' (if it already exists, it is 'updated')... adjusting attribute values doesn't fire any events